# Google Spreadsheet - return values to multiple columns

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to do something that is beyond my  junior coding capabilities.  I have created a function that will parse API data into Google Spreadsheet, but no matter what I've tried (and searched online for answers), the results are only being posted to a single column.

The code I am using currently is:

```
function getAPIdata (URL,key){
  var apiurl = "https://example.com/Site/"+URL+"/students?&ID="+key
  var rank_data = parse(apiurl)
  var result = []
  var data_dictionary = rank_data.Student
  for (var i in data_dictionary){
  result.push(data_dictionary[i].Name)
  result.push(data_dictionary[i].Grade)
  }  
  return result
}
```

The data in question that is being parsed is

```
Student": [
{
    "Name": ​Adam,
    "Grade": 75
},
{
    "Name": ​Alan,
    "Grade": 90
}
```

What is happening is that when I call the function in excel I am getting a single column with:

```
Adam 
75
Alan
90
```

What I would like to do is have the following (spaces here delineate another column)

```
Adam    75
Alan    90
```

Basically, I have a 1x4 output and I would like a 2x2 output. Is there anyway I could do this?  I realize I can call the function twice and push different data sets each time, but in this case I can only call the API once for all data.  I thought about potentially pulling the data, caching it but before I delve down learning a path that will not bear fruit, I was hoping some of the experts here could weigh in.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [] and push a row at a time, like

```
function getAPIdata (URL,key){
  var apiurl = "https://example.com/Site/"+URL+"/students?&ID="+key
  var rank_data = parse(apiurl)
  var result = []
  var data_dictionary = rank_data.Student
  for (var i in data_dictionary){
    result.push([data_dictionary[i].Name, data_dictionary[i].Grade])
  }  
  return result
}
```

Comment: That is amazing - works like a charm!  I'll need to read into this to understand the logic - thanks Olof